# Make babel exclude test files

Tags: node.js, babeljs

On my build step I'm using babel to transpile the code to es5 (from `src` to `dist`). How do I make it exclude files ending in `.test.js`?

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015" ],
  "ignore": "\\.test\\.js"
}
```

Comment: I found the babelrc did not work but the inline compiler option did

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Based on the documentation, you should be able to write `.babelrc`

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "**/*.test.js"
  ]
}
```

However, I was able to verify that this does not seem to work. I tried it with version 6.5.1 (babel-core 6.5.2).

At the same time, the following does work:

```
babel src --out-dir build --ignore '**/*.test.js'
```

That is the same glob pattern as written in the `.babelrc` file. If you install any glob library from npm you'll find that this glob pattern would work (that is how I came up with it...I do not currently use babel).

Comment: I tried "**/*.test.js", "src/**/*.test.js", "src/index.test.js". It still compiles `src\index.test.js -> dist\index.test.js`

Comment: I've edited the answer...it seems that the `.bablerc` ignore is not honored. I've noticed several variations of this being reported on their github issue tracker. Try it via command line flag `--ignore` and you'll noticed the glob pattern is honored.

Comment: The file should be named .babelrc not .bablerc

Comment: I tried the workaround with CLI, and I just noticed that `'` on both side of `**/*.test.js` is important to make this work. Otherwise, seems it recognizes glob weird. I have no idea..

Comment: @PlusbPreco The reason you need to wrap the glob in quotes is that this makes it pass to babel as a string, which babel will then use to match files. If the argument is unquoted, the shell will expand it using its own rules before passing that on to babel.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of the files that Babel includes by default? How would I find that out?

Answer (score 19):

As of today, the following works in .babelrc 
(babel-core: v6.26.3)

```
"ignore": [
  "**/__tests__", // ignore the whole test directory
  "**/*.test.js" // ignore test files only
]
```